# new version Jetpack Compose AndroidView works wrong in low-version Android such as Android 7 android Android 10

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

### Solution: change SurfaceView to TextureView, though I don't known why ,but thanks @Halifax

About AndroidView bug
[the layout here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65Ose.png)
the code:

```kotlin
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Composable
fun IjkPlayer(player: IjkMediaPlayer, activityVar: ActivityVar) {
    // https://juejin.cn/post/7034363130121551903
    AndroidView(
        factory = { context ->
            SwithunLog.d("AndroidView # factory")
            val surfaceView = SurfaceView(context)
            surfaceView.holder.addCallback(object : SurfaceHolder.Callback {
                override fun surfaceCreated(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
                    // surfaceView在activity Stop时会destroy，重新切到前台会重新走create，这里要重新setDisplay
                    // 否则会黑屏但是有声音 https://github.com/Bilibili/ijkplayer/issues/2666#issuecomment-800083756
                    player.setDisplay(holder)
                    player.start()
                }

                override fun surfaceChanged(
                    holder: SurfaceHolder,
                    format: Int,
                    width: Int,
                    height: Int,
                ) {
                }

                override fun surfaceDestroyed(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
                    player.pause()
                }

            })

            activityVar.mySurfaceView = surfaceView

            surfaceView
        },
        modifier = Modifier.width(100.dp).height(100.dp),
        update = {
            SwithunLog.d("AndroidView # update")
        })
}
```

it works right on Android12
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfrjY.png)

but on Android 7 and Android 10
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzf4u.png)
it works wrong, every thing is black only the AndroidView, but the button on the left still can be clicked, just cannot be seen
「the layout inspector shows the same like the first picker on Android 7,10,12」

---

this happens after I update some library about compose, before that, all devices are works fine

```
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.3.3"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.3.3"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.6.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.3.3"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.3.3"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:1.3.3"
```

I have search on Internet, Android I have try `surfaceView.post { // setlayoutParam width and height here }`

Comment: try `surfaceView.setBackgroundColor.(android.R.color.transparent)`, it may be related to how surface is being drawn on different platforms

Comment: @PhilDukhov thanks, but it still not work
```
            val surfaceView = SurfaceView(context)

            surfaceView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.transparent))
            surfaceView.holder.addCallback(object : SurfaceHolder.Callback {```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to continue using `SurfaceView` instead of switching to `TextureView` you can use `Modifier.clipToBounds()`

Answer (score 0):

Please try to set your `SurfaceView` width and height，Modify `LayoutParams`。

What you need to solve now is to cover the content of the left button area。

Comment: ```
            SwithunLog.d("AndroidView # factory")
            val surfaceView = SurfaceView(context)

            surfaceView.post {
                surfaceView.layoutParams.width = 10
                surfaceView.layoutParams.height = 10
            }

            surfaceView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.transparent))
            surfaceView.holder.addCallback(object : SurfaceHolder.Callback {```
  it still not works, not just cover the left button area ,the whole screen is black, only the surfaceview is showing

Comment: Try TextureView, is it possible that there is an animation transition in your code?

Comment: Thank you, TextureView works  :D